# Chrome v53 - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, laravel-mix

I have a Vue.js application running on signage device of LG.
Up untill yesterday no issue. But I performed some updates and now the signage device gives the error below in the console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags. 
/node_modules/@vue/shared/dist/shared.esm-bundler.js @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:85
__webpack_require__ @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2538
(anonymous function) @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:38
./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:52
__webpack_require__ @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2538
(anonymous function) @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:129
./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:63
__webpack_require__ @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2538
(anonymous function) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:149
./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:74
__webpack_require__ @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2538
(anonymous function) @ vue.esm-bundler.js:150
./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2481
__webpack_require__ @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2538
(anonymous function) @ lg-player.js:2
./resources/js/lg-player.js @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:777
__webpack_require__ @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2538
__webpack_require__.O @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2708
__webpack_require__.O @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2575
(anonymous function) @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2709
(anonymous function) @ lg-player.js?id=2307a1f…:2711
```

However the same application runs smoothly in my dev environment (which is a recent chrome version). I would suppose there is a compatibility problem between how this code is bundled (Laravel Mix / Webpack) vs what Chrome 53 supports. But after hours of reverting changes / switching commits / changing npm package versions ... I feel a bit lost.

I also tried to use laravel mix polyfill (https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/polyfill) and the code to

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-polyfill');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .polyfill({
      enabled: true,
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      targets: "chrome 53"
   });
```

But that didn't change anything.
Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: "Chrome 53" - where does this reference point come from and how is it related to "LG" device? The error means that unsupported regex syntax is used in Vue lib itself. It's most likely happened after Vue update, so this narrow down the problem and the way to solve it. It doesn't make sense to polyfil syntax features. . node_modules aren't transpiled by default. It may be possible to use the current lib version but then this requires to process it with Babel and specific transforms  like `@babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex`, but a specific flag that causes the error should be detected

Comment: 'Chrome 53' comes from executing this:
navigator.appVersion
"5.0 (Web0S; Linux/SmartTV) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.34 Safari/537.36 WebAppManager"

Comment: The vue update definitely makes sense. On the working commit I'm on Vue 3.1.1 and now I'm on 3.2.42. However trying to revert vue to 3.1.1 breaks all kind of other packages that are update and need > 3.1.1. If I remove all vue packages and start from schratch with 3.1.1 and then install all vue related packages the error is still there...

Comment: You need to check the actual vue packages versions in node_modules - `@vue/shared`, etc. I don't know what's your routine for handling deps, but in any suspicious situation they need to be reinstalled, i.e. node_modules should be removed and installed from scratch. From what I see here, it's likely that dotAll flag is in use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#specifications . Forcing `@vue/*` deps to be processed by Babel in Webpack would likely fix this but this can add a handful of other problems

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Now removed node_modules folder and package-lock.json. Then copied package.json from a working commit to my local branch. New 'npm install' and still the same issue. Had to change a lot of files because in the meantime upgrade Inertia to 1.x, so reverted those changes. Even after doing that and having the exact same package.json as on a working commit this error persists...

Comment: Removing a lock is a potential mistake. This forces package versions to be out of control and shouldn't be done without a reason. Any way, at this point this requires to debug the app, the question can't be solved without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You can get a copy of portable Chrome (Chromium) 53 or lower and debug the error locally